# Should I use a column to count rows or count them in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, pdo

Which is best practice?

Scenario: If I have 2 tables, one called `topics` and another called `posts` whereby each post belongs to a specific `topic_id`.

Would it be best to have a column in the `topics` table called `post_count` which I would update whenever a post is created/delete under that `topic_id`.

Or would it be best to count the number of rows where a `topic_id` matches using a SELECT COUNT query?

Are there any disadvantages to either or differences in efficiency?

Comment: i prefer to always update the topics table. so, if 1 topic has 10000++ post, and the user only want to know how much post its has, then the query can be faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing `post_count` on column is a [denormalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization).

The read performance will be faster to look up a single field than to perform a `SELECT COUNT`, but most people would agree that this is a premature optimisation that introduces the possiblity of update anomaly. The database should store normalised (i.e. non-redundant) data unless you have benchmarks indicating that this is the performance bottleneck in your application.

You would probably be better served by looking at a caching layer between the database and the application so that the count is not performed each time you query the database, but will be updated when the contents of `posts` changes - you may even find that MySQL is [already caching the result](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44266/does-mysql-cache-queries).

Comment: Would it also be practical if I had a functionality which periodically checked the accuracy of the `post_count` column by comparing it to a `SELECT COUNT`? (Something that would be scheduled for every week or so and can also be manually done by an admin)

Comment: It really depends on the stage of your application's lifecycle, and indeed your mentality/methodology. I would say that if you have a working, deployed application that has thousands to millions of topics and posts, and you have identified a noticeable performance issue with this particular query that caching can not mitigate, then go for it. Otherwise I would say forget it - don't waste your time introducing possible bugs when you could be working on real features.

Comment: For fun I ran some times on a postgresql database on my laptop (i.e. non-scientific), first with 200 records then with 200k records. See results: http://pastebin.com/C6xRy6K3 . The SELECT COUNT was actually faster for smaller number of posts.